# C# BouncyCastle FIPS RSA keys to RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

BouncyCastle has [FIPS DLLs](https://www.bouncycastle.org/fips-csharp/) for C# that I need to use for encryption instead of normal DLLs because of compliance. How do you import public and private keys and covert them to a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in order to encrypt and decrypt.

---

This is how I encrypt and decrypt using the regular BouncyCastle. I just need to change the functions `ImportPrivateKey` and `ImportPublicKey`

```
public static string Decrypt(string privateKey, string base64Encrypted)
{
    string ret = null;
    using (var rsa = ImportPrivateKey(privateKey))
    {
        var cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encrypted);
        RSA rsaCng = new RSACng();
        rsaCng.ImportParameters(rsa.ExportParameters(true));
        byte[] plainBytes = rsaCng.Decrypt(cipherBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
        string plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes);
        ret = plaintext;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

```
public static string Encrypt(string publicKey, string toEncrypt)
{
    string cipherText = null;
    using (var rsa = ImportPublicKey(publicKey))
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt);
        RSA rsaCng = new RSACng();
        rsaCng.ImportParameters(rsa.ExportParameters(false));
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = rsaCng.Encrypt(data, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
        cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

```
public RSACryptoServiceProvider ImportPrivateKey(string pem)
{
    PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(pem));
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair KeyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pr.ReadObject();
    RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)KeyPair.Private);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
    return rsa;
}
```

```
public RSACryptoServiceProvider ImportPublicKey(string pem)
{
    PemReader pr = new PemReader(new StringReader(pem));
    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pr.ReadObject();
    RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)publicKey);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
    return rsa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it working. If someone else has something more simple that would be awesome!. Import the keys turn them into `AsymmetricRsaPublicKey` then covert them to `RSAParameters` and then import those.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Asymmetric;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Fips;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
```

```
public RSACryptoServiceProvider ImportPublicKey(string key)
{
    var reader = new OpenSslPemReader(new StringReader(key));
    var publicKeyInfo = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo)reader.ReadObject();
    var rpckp = new AsymmetricRsaPublicKey(FipsRsa.Pkcs1v15.Algorithm, publicKeyInfo);
    RSAParameters parms = new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = rpckp.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        Exponent = rpckp.PublicExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
    };
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rcsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rcsp.ImportParameters(parms);
    return rcsp;
}
```

```
public RSACryptoServiceProvider ImportPrivateKey(string key)
{
    var reader = new OpenSslPemReader(new StringReader(key));
    var keyPair = (PemKeyPair)reader.ReadObject();
    var rpckp = new AsymmetricRsaPrivateKey(FipsRsa.Pkcs1v15.Algorithm, keyPair.PrivateKeyInfo);
    RSAParameters parms = new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = rpckp.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        P = rpckp.P.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        Q = rpckp.Q.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        DP = rpckp.DP.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        DQ = rpckp.DQ.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        InverseQ = rpckp.QInv.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        D = rpckp.PrivateExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        Exponent = rpckp.PublicExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
    };
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rcsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rcsp.ImportParameters(parms);
    return rcsp;
}
```

Comment: Import of private key errored occasionally in unit tests so in my code I when generating keys I added a loop with a try/catch to make sure that if import doesn't work new keys are generated.